# Attempting to load module, however when trying to compile the module the computer states that several structs are undefined

Tags: c, linux, struct, makefile

The purpose of this module is to basically do the same thing as what happens when you type into your linux command line cat /proc/buddyinfo

Code

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/mmzone.h>

#define DRIVER_AUTHOR "Matthew James Barnes <mbarnes2k5@Gmail.com>"
#define DRIVER_DESC     "A driver that does the same thing as /proc/buddyinfo"

/***
 *GLOBAL VARIABLES
 ***/
extern struct pglist_data *first_online_pgdat(void);
extern struct pglist_data *next_online_pgdat(struct pglist_data*pgdat);
struct pglist_data *pgdat;
extern struct zone *zone;


int init_module(void)
{
int order;
for(pgdat = first_online_pgdat(); pgdat; pgdat = next_online_pgdat(pgdat))
{
for(zone = pgdat->node_zones; zone; zone = next_zone(zone)){
printk(KERN_INFO "Node %d, zone %8s ",pgdat->node_id, zone->name);
printk(KERN_INFO "Node %d", pgdat->node_id);
printk(KERN_CONT "Zone %s",zone->name);
for( order = 0; order < MAX_ORDER; ++order)
        printk(KERN_CONT "%6lu ", zone->free_area[order].nr_free);
printk(KERN_CONT "\n");
}
}
return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void){
        printk(KERN_INFO "Zones have been feenished.\n");
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR(DRIVER_AUTHOR);
MODULE_DESCRIPTION(DRIVER_DESC);

~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
~
```

I decided to go lean and create a makefile as well as a folder within my kernel called module-edits.

In module edits when I run the makefile, I run into a compilation error.

The command line returns the following:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/build M=/usr/local/share/source_code/version1/module-edits modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
ERROR: "next_online_pgdat" [/usr/local/share/source_code/version1/module-edits/printbuddy.ko] undefined!

ERROR: "next_zone" [/usr/local/share/source_code/version1/module-edits/printbuddy.ko] undefined!

ERROR: "zone" [/usr/local/share/source_code/version1/module-edits/printbuddy.ko] undefined!

ERROR: "first_online_pgdat" [/usr/local/share/source_code/version1/module-edits/printbuddy.ko] undefined!
make[2]:  [scripts/Makefile.modpost:94: __modpost] Error 1
make[1]:  [Makefile:1632: modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
make:  [makefile:5: all] Error 2
```

Now, what is baffling about this is that when I typed

`#include <linux/mmzone.h>`

there are a number of structs.

```
pgdat is a struct that allows access to the current page data.

*first_online_pgdat(void); is a function that points to the first page. 

*next_online_pgdat(struct pglist_data*pgdat); points to the next page.

struct pglist_data *pgdat; 

is basically the representation of my page.

and extern struct zone *zone is the representation of the zone type of the pages.
```

All of this is included in mmzone, but it's as if the functions in mmzone.h are not even being referenced.

I don't really understand what is going on, but I would appreciate assistance from experienced linux programmers.

Comment: Stupid question, probably, but did you compile your kernel?

Comment: I actually DID before this, I did not install the compiled kernel though because this file here? It didn't get compiled with the kernel so I decided to go the insmod route instead. I rolled back my kernel to my current version though because I made a bit of a mess.

Comment: So I rolled back my kernel and now I'm trying to do insmod, problem being I'm still where I started. I can't do the make command for this file because it says that everything that should be defined in linux/mmzone.h is 'undefined'

Comment: These errors look more like linking errors than compilation errors. Did you try the verbose mode (`make V=1 ...`) to see the full commands?

Comment: No I didn't even know I could do that.

Comment: what would be the full command to get verbose mode?

Comment: The same but with `V=1`: `make V=1 -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/build -M...`